# Merge two $lookup collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Here i am try to get aggregated result from my `challenge` collection with `challengeusers` and `challengeusers` has the user_id and i used $lookup to join the users too.

When i use this query, i am getting following output.

```
"challenges": [
    {
        "_id": "5b7bf6fd87ec106308d7e3c1",
        "start_date": "2018-08-09T12:40:21.470Z",
        "end_date": "2018-08-05T12:40:21.470Z",
        "challnegedusers": [
            {
                "chalenge_id": "5b7bf6fd87ec106308d7e3c1",
                "user_id": "5b75623db457045e3bb12e0a",
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "user_id": "5b75643c0a97791bcc9ed64c",
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "user_id": "5b756144b457045e3bb12e08",
                "status": 1
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "_id": "5b756144b457045e3bb12e08",
                "first_name": "XYZ"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5b75623db457045e3bb12e0a",
                "first_name": "BAC"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5b75643c0a97791bcc9ed64c",
                "first_name": "YTA"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But i want the `challengeusers` and `users` to merge in a single object.

Most of all i want the `status` of `challengeusers` with user's info.

expected output:

```
"challenges": [
    {
        "_id": "5b7bf6fd87ec106308d7e3c1",
        "start_date": "2018-08-09T12:40:21.470Z",
        "end_date": "2018-08-05T12:40:21.470Z",
        "challnegedusers": [
            {
                "user_id": "5b75623db457045e3bb12e0a",
                "status": 1,
                "first_name": "BAC"
            },
            {
                "user_id": "5b75643c0a97791bcc9ed64c",
                "status": 1,
                "first_name": "YTA"
            },
            {
                "user_id": "5b756144b457045e3bb12e08",
                "status": 1,
                "first_name": "XYZ"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

MongoDB Aggregate Query that i am using.

```
        let challenges = await ChallengeModel.aggregate([
            { $match: criteria },
            { $lookup: {
                from: 'challengeusers',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'challenge_id',
                as: 'challnegedusers'
            } },
            { $lookup: {
                    from: 'appusers',
                    localField: 'challnegedusers.user_id',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'users'
            } },
            { $sort: {created_at: -1}}
        ]);
```

Comment: what is your mongodb version?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v3.6.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in mongodb **3.6**

```
ChallengeModel.aggregate([
  { "$match": criteria },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "challengeusers",
    "let": { "challengeusersId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$challenge_id", "$$challengeusersId" ] } } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "appusers",
        "let": { "user_id": "$user_id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$user_id" ] } } },
        ],
        "as": "user"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$user" },
      { "$addFields": { "first_name": "$user.first_name" }},
      { "$project": { "user": 0 }}
    ],
    "as": "challnegedusers"
  }}
])
```

And with your approach you can try this

```
ChallengeModel.aggregate([
  { "$match": criteria },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "challengeusers",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "challenge_id",
    "as": "challnegedusers"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "challnegedusers" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "appusers",
    "localField": "challnegedusers.user_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "challnegedusers.user"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "challnegedusers.user" },
  { "$addFields": { "challnegedusers.first_name": "$challnegedusers.user.first_name" }},
  { "$sort": { "created_at": -1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "start_date": { "$first": "$start_date" }
    "end_date": { "$first": "$end_date" },
    "challnegedusers": { "$push": "$challnegedusers" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: First query is working as i wanted it to be. Thank you. You're a hero. :)